# class path resource [WEB-INF/web.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, web.xml

Maybe someone faced such a problem. The web.xml file is on the WEB-INF/web.xml path, but the error says otherwise.

```
2022-11-16 17:40:56.120  WARN 3272 --- [main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : 
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh
attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Unsatisfied
dependency expressed through field 'webXmlRolesParser'; nested exception
is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating
bean with name 'webXmlRolesParser' defined in class path resource
[by/belinvest/panel/admin/config/SecurityConfiguration.class]: Invocation
of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException:
class path resource [WEB-INF/web.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Instead [edit] your question to include the relevant code and error as (appropriately formatted) text.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I fixed image and wrote text of code

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and solved it by removing the following line (located in the SpringBootApplication class):

<s>`@ImportResource("classpath:web.xml")`</s>

The purpose of Springs @ImportResource annotation is to import Spring bean configurations and not for importing servlet configurations.